# help with a HTML nested list that creates a sub nav

Tags: jquery, html, css, overflow, css-position

I am having trouble with my nested list that creates a subnav. Currently it is positioned absolutely, but I can not have it's parent positioned relatively as the overflow on the parents parent is hidden so the user cannot see the full sub nav, can anyone shed any light on a fix for this please?

[Subnav Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7VkrG/52/)

Plese see the link for a jsfiddle example of what I mean.

Comment: If you describe how you want this to work it would be a little easier to assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/7VkrG/53/

You need to remove `overflow:hidden` on `nav` and give it a height instead e.g. `34px`.

```
header nav {
  width:960px;
  border:1px solid red;
  height: 34px;  
}
```

Then you will want to adjust the positioning of the subnav so that it displays in the right place:

```
header nav li ul.dropdown {top: 5px;}
```